# How to hide items in the action dropdown of a form view in odoo9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to hide two options from the action drop down of a from view. When I searched I saw it is added by using the act_window. How can I hide those items.

Please see this image too..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumP5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I deleted the original act_window record and created a new one and changed the action for the "Put Money IN" and "Take Money Out" buttons in the sheet. Following is the code,

```
  <delete id="point_of_sale.action_pos_box_in" model="ir.actions.act_window"/>
  <delete id="point_of_sale.action_pos_box_out" model="ir.actions.act_window"/>

  <record id="misc_action_pos_box_in" model="ir.actions.act_window">
       <field name="name">Put Money In</field>
       <field name="res_model">cash.box.in</field>
       <field name="view_mode">form</field>
       <field name="target">new</field>
       <field name="src_model">pos.session</field>
       <field name="key2"></field>
   </record>

   <record id="misc_action_pos_box_out" model="ir.actions.act_window">
       <field name="name">Take Money Out</field>
       <field name="res_model">cash.box.out</field>
       <field name="view_mode">form</field>
       <field name="target">new</field>
       <field name="src_model">pos.session</field>
       <field name="key2"></field>
   </record>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="misc_view_pos_session_form">
       <field name="name">misc.pos.session.form</field>
       <field name="model">pos.session</field>
       <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_session_form"/>
       <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//sheet//div[@name='button_box']//button[1]" position="replace">
               <button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(misc_action_pos_box_in)d"
                       type="action" icon="fa-level-down"
                       attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('cash_control', '=', False), ('state', 'not in', ['opened', 'closing_control'])]}">
                   <div class="o_form_field o_stat_info">
                       <span class="o_stat_text">Put</span>
                       <span class="o_stat_text">Money In</span>
                   </div>
               </button>
           </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//sheet//div[@name='button_box']//button[2]" position="replace">
               <button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(misc_action_pos_box_out)d"
                       type="action" icon="fa-level-up"
                       attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('cash_control', '=', False), ('state', 'not in', ['opened', 'closing_control'])]}">
                   <div class="o_form_field o_stat_info">
                       <span class="o_stat_text">Take</span>
                       <span class="o_stat_text">Money Out</span>
                   </div>
               </button>
           </xpath>
       </field>
   </record>
```